# Problema com certificado CIELO usando Django

Tags: python, django, ssl, pagamento-online

Estou tentando implementar um checkout transparente para minha loja online usando a CIELO para tal.

dados: 
Django 1.9.5
Python 2.7.6
Ubuntu 14.04
nginx
uwgsi
digital ocean

link api python cielo: https://github.com/DeveloperCielo/API-3.0-Python

Instalei os certificados usando o script cielo.sh disponibilizado neste link: https://developercielo.github.io/Webservice-3.0/

Quando rodo qualquer código exemplo da api tenho o seguinte erro:

> Exception Type:   SSLError 
>   Exception Value:  hostname 'apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br' doesn't match either of '*.braspag.com.br', 'braspag.com.br'

Alguém pode me ajudar? Indiciaria outra API para soluções em pagamentos?

Answer (score 0):

É um problema com o certificado de SSL.

Você deve verificar se o certificado SSL foi gerado para o dominio que você está utilizando.

Uma outra maneira é ignorar a checagem do certificado - mas que fique bem claro que isso deixa o sistema vulnerável a certos tipos de ataque [man-in-the-middle](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_man-in-the-middle).